# Synchronizing tasks from Sharepoint list to Outlook task list

Tags: sharepoint, outlook

I seem to be facing a problem when having to use the task function in Outlook.

When an online sharepoint list is to be 'synchronized' with the task list in Outlook, it gives me the following error:

Task 'SharePoint' reported error (0x80004005) : 'Failed to copy one or more items. For details, see the log file.'

Now I have tried to check google for sugestions to solve this, but all of the suggestions seem not to be working.

Could a problem be that I am using Windows Explorer 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be related with attachments in the task item. Check whether attachments have subject that ends with a dot.

When I attach a mail which contains a subject that ends with a dot, task synchronization fails with the following error message:

```
Task 'SharePoint' reported error (0x80004005) : 'One or more items failed to copy. Changes that were made to their attachments are not compatible with the server. 

The failed items were moved to your Local Failures folder and replaced with copies from the server. If you need assistance troubleshooting items in your Local Failures folder, a Help topic is available at the following address: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70300. For details, see the log file .'
```